# Check the value exist in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, get

I am trying to make a condition of getting value but it is not working actually I have 3 pages and the layout of the page is same only the form is changed so what I am trying to do is if pagename?page is set then do something otherwise show recent activities in normal php it is easy to do by using isset() function but in codeigniter the isset function is not working here is what i did

```
<?php 
    if($this->input->get('page') == true) {
        if($this->input->get('page')  == true && $this->input->get('page') == 'page1') {
            echo 'page 01';
        }
        if($this->input->get('page')  == true && $this->input->get('page') == 'page2') {
            echo 'page 02';
        }
    } else {
        //normal activities page to be shown
    }
?>
```

This is what I am trying to do but nothing is working for me like it's directly jumping to else condition can anyone help me our please if not clarified do ask me please.

Thank You and hoping to learn

Comment: Is page name pass by URL?? and post your all code

Comment: yes it is passed by url not page name just as parameter like orders?page=one two or three that I cannot say it as page but I t will be shown a form

Comment: Post controller code

Comment: have you set `$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;` ?

Comment: Why you are repeating `$this->input->get('page')  == true && `?

Comment: @MarkAlan Check the answers below added

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
if($this->input->get('page')) {
    if($this->input->get('page') == 'page1') {
        echo 'page 01';
    } else if($this->input->get('page') == 'page2') {
        echo 'page 02';
    }
} else {
    //normal activities page to be shown
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

```
switch($this->input->get('page')) {
  case 'page1':
    echo 'page 01';
    break;

  case 'page2':
    echo 'page 02';
    break;

  default:
  /* normal activities page to be shown */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In View**

```
<a href="<?php echo  base_url() ?>index.php/controller_name/order/one">Page One</a>
<a href="<?php echo  base_url() ?>index.php/controller_name/order/two">Page two</a>
<a href="<?php echo  base_url() ?>index.php/controller_name/order/three">Page three</a>
```

**In Controller**

```
public function order($value)
{
    switch ($value) {
        case 'one':
            $page = 'one';
            break;

        case 'two':
            $page = 'two';
            break;

        case 'three':
            $page = 'three';
            break;

        default:
            $page = 'three';
            break;
    }
    echo $page;
}
```

Comment: @MarkAlan Check this